# PHP5.3 Oriented Object Modeling for HTML generation, a possibility or performance bottleneck?

Tags: zend-framework, dom, php-5.3, oop, phpquery

The main motivation in this is that I was very tired or using php tags to write php views that were very ugly. Consider this approach:

```
<?php
<ul>
    <?php echo foreach($products as $product): ?>
    <li><?php echo $product->getName()?><li>
</ul>
```

This is the basic approach of trivial MVC with views, but I was tired of that, so I use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) instead:

```
<?php
$ul = pq('<ul />');

foreach($products as $product) {
    $ul->append(pq('<li />')
        ->html($product->getName())
    );
}

echo $ul;
```

This is much cleaner. Unfortunately, phpQuery does not seem active on development. The thing is, phpQuery is programmed in a procedural way and is really hard to understand and maintain and contains some bugs that make it rather useless in most DOM manipulation cases. I was thinking of writing an OO approach to DOM writing based on jQuery using Zend Framework's component [Zend_Dom_Query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html), with the same approach of phpQuery: same interface as jQuery.

After some search on the net on PHP HTML Generators, I cannot seem to find much that has been done on that part, and my question is, **is using OO with PHP to generate HTML a performance bottleneck, since all static HTML would be server side generated?**

I know there is the HAML approach, but I like the idea of DOM manipulation, so that it is possible to inject html at any time anywhere during the script execution. DOM manipulation on the server side leads to view script inheritence like this:

```
//a parent index.phtml
$container = pq('<div />')
    ->addClass('.container')
    ->html($this->_("Hello World!"));

$this->setRenderReturn($container);

//a child index.phtml
$container = $this->renderParent(__FILE__); //retrieves the parent just like the conventional parent:: in php scripts
$container->addClass('anotherClass');

$this->setRenderReturn($container);
```

Also, in case I missed a PHP library that does just that, I would gladly appreciate if someone could point me to it.

Answer (score 2):

In direct answer to your question...

> is using OO with PHP to generate HTML a performance bottleneck, since all static HTML would be server side generated?

Yes.

You should have a look at [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) and particularly the extensions added in Symfony 2. It supports template inheritance as well as named sections for overwriting / inserting markup.

Comment: I have been looking at it a bit and it seems very powerful in any use cases that I have. I wonder though, can you easily manipulate an element with conditionals? Here's an example with phpQuery: http://pastebin.com/SFT4rMyJ and see the conditional where I can dynamically add a class to an unfinished element before putting its html. What would be the twig equivalent? --Best regards